# Browser cant find file or directory in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a qr code and store it on disk. Running the program from my pc works fine, but when I run it on the server (deploy is done in docker), I get this error:

```
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/QR/QR-1-9.png'
```

and the browser also points me to this line of my code

```
    with open(UPLOADS_PATHS, 'wb') as f:
```

The route is defined in the settings file like this:

```
    QR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/QR')
```

And this is the view where the qr is stored on disk

```
    nombre_archivo = f'QR-{request.user.instituto.id}-{idRecibo}.png'

    UPLOADS_PATHS = os.path.join(settings.QR_ROOT, nombre_archivo)

    with open(UPLOADS_PATHS, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

I try this on settings.py:

```
    QR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './static/QR')
```

but it does not work

Comment: There is a space after QR?

Answer (score 0):

I see a space here **/QR /**

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/QR /QR-1-9.png'`

Comment: That was a typo when I wrote the question.  I already edited it. Thanks for point it out!